# OAuth in JIRA with JQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, jira

I'm making a client application where the user must login using JIRA, similar like other apps where you grant permission to your credentials and access right away the application.

I followed the instructions and I'm setting up my client using this [reference](https://developer.atlassian.com/server/jira/platform/jira-rest-api-example-oauth-authentication-6291692/) I'm sending my request to `MY_BASE_URL + "/plugins/servlet/oauth/request-token"` but I'm getting a empty response and a CORS error that the request didn succeded.

My question is consuming the api endpoints via javascript is even possible? , I searched a lot here and inside the forums of Atlassian and I the only thing I found is this [question](https://community.atlassian.com/t5/Jira-questions/Jira-OAuth-Authentication-using-Jquery-Ajax/qaq-p/259875) which is unanswered.

```
$("#authenticate").click(function(){
jQuery.ajax({
    //The URL to process the request
    'url': BASE_URL+'/plugins/servlet/oauth/request-token',
    'headers':{
        'Access-Control-Allow-Origin':'*'
    },
    'type': 'GET',
    'success': function (data) {
        alert('Request token is: ' + data);
    }
});
});
```

Comment: Are you using Jira Cloud? Or Jira Server?